# string manipulation preg_replace or str_replace

Tags: php, string, pcre

I need to replace a word with another word. But

```
$var= str_replace($linklabel[$k], $linklabelmod[$k], $var);
```

is not giving the desired result. For example i have a string

```
$var="the theory of them thesis"; 
$linklabel[1]="the"; 
$linklabelmod[1]="hhh";
```

What i need is, i just want to replace the word "the". But since "the" is repeated in "theory" "thesis" and "them", all those starting three letters are also getting replaced. Then output becomes 
**$var="hhh hhhory of hhhm hhhsis";//wrong** 
But i need the output 
**$var="hhh theory of them thesis";//write**
I am bad at explaining a question, plz excuse me...

Thanks in advance....

---

From what I (paxdiablo) can gather from the OP's comments, this is the code following modifications (still claimed not to work):

```
foreach($xpath->query('//a') as $element) {
    $linklabel[] = $element->textContent;
    $link[] = $element->getAttribute("href");
    $i=$i+1;
}
for($k=0;$k<$i;$k++) {
    $linklabelmod[$k] = str_replace($linklabel[$k], $linklabel[$k]."[$k]", $linklabel[$k]);
    $var = preg_replace ('/\b'.preg_quote($linklabel[$k]).'\b/', $linklabelmod[$k], $var);
}
print $var; //printing web page
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert white space :) if you want to use str_replace function

`php > $var = "the theory of them thesis";`

`php > $var = str_replace(array(" the ", "the "), 'hhh', $var);`

`php > echo $var;`

Comment: You also have to add white spaces to `'hhh'`.

Comment: Although this will work for the string given this will also change words ending in `the` to hhh too. EG `lathe ` would be replaced as `lahhh` as well as ignoring any `the` preceding any punctuation. So while it will work for this particular instance (`hhh` space issue notwithstanding) it's flawed as a general pattern.

Comment: The problem is that the example given from the OP is not related with the real code he needs to change.

Answer (score 5):

The normal way of doing what you want is to use a regular expression replace with word boundaries:

```
$var = preg_replace ('/\bthe\b/', 'hhh', $var);
```

or:

```
$var = preg_replace ('/\b'.preg_quote($linklabel[$k]).'\b/', $linklabelmod[$k], $var);
```

Comment: plz , can u give me an example. I am new to php reg expressions...Thx

Comment: $var = preg_replace( "\b$linklabel[$k]\b", $linklabelmod[$k], $var, 1 ); // is this u a telling, once again, i am totally new to preg_replace

Comment: You are missing delimiters I think ;)

Comment: preg_replace('/\b'.$linklabel[$k].'\b/i',$linklabelmod[$k], $var);

Comment: You have also forgot to use preg_qoute as your matching this way.

Comment: excuse me, this is not working for me. I am noob and i don't know y. It is still replacing all the matching letters from the words...This is the code
foreach($xpath->query('//a') as $element) {
     $linklabel[] = $element->textContent;
     $link[] = $element->getAttribute("href");
  $i=$i+1;
}

for($k=0;$k<$i;$k++) {
 $linklabelmod[$k] = str_replace($linklabel[$k], $linklabel[$k]."[$k]", $linklabel[$k]);
$var = preg_replace ('/\b'.preg_quote($linklabel[$k]).'\b/', $linklabelmod[$k], $var);
}
print $var;//printing web page

Answer (score 3):

Well i would always advise in using str_replace over preg_replace but in this case you might have to.

```
<?php

$k = 1;
$var="the theory of them thesis";
$linklabel[1]="the"; 
$linklabelmod[1]="hhh";

$var = preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($linklabel[$k]).'\b/i',$linklabelmod[$k], $var);

?>
```

Dont forget to preg_qoute the text to minimize the amount of errors

Comment: nope, this is not giving the result

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'p' in C:\wamp\www\test\f.php on line 21

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '0' in C:\wamp\www\test\f.php on line 21

Comment: yea sorry, speedy fingers get away from me!

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function preg_qoute() in C:\wamp\www\test\f.php on line 20 .. How to define preg_qoute();

Comment: i made a spelling mistake, try now :)

Comment: Now its showing 
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'p' in C:\wamp\www\test\f.php on line 20

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '0' in C:\wamp\www\test\f.php on line 20

Comment: I tried the version without `preg_quote()`, and I didn't get any error messages.  
@Kiran George: If you are using the function with the same exact code, then you should not get such errors (where is the `p` modifier in a string like `/\bthe\b/i`?). You would probably get the right answer if you show the actual code you are using.

Comment: Also the preg_qoute will modify the text your finding so it will auto escape any special chars that may effect the regex string.

Answer (score -2):

```
$var = "the theory of them thesis"; 
$linklabel[1] = "the"; 
$linklabelmod[1] = "hhh";

$var = str_replace( " " . $linklabel[1] . " ", 
                    " " . $linklabelmod[1] . " ", 
                    " " . $var . " ");
$var = trim($var);
```

Comment: this also not working. Here is my code **foreach($xpath->query('//a') as $element) {
     $linklabel[] = $element->textContent;
     $link[] = $element->getAttribute("href");
  $i=$i+1;
}

for($k=0;$k<$i;$k++) {
 $linklabelmod[$k] = str_replace($linklabel[$k], $linklabel[$k]."[$k]", $linklabel[$k]);
 $var = str_replace( " " . $linklabel[$k] . " ", " " . $linklabelmod[$k] . " ", " " . $var . " ");
}
print $var;//printing web page**

Comment: excuse me, may be i am a noob, but it is not woring for me

Comment: The code reported in the answer works as expected. @Kiran George: Both this solution, and the one using `preg_replace()` work; if they are not working in your case, then you should report the exact code you are using; people don't have the crystal ball to debug your code.